# AJAX request in wordpress wont return anything but 400

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Ive seen over 10 videos and read a lot here on stack overflow. I am basically overwhelmed and unable to process anything at this point. I just want to get a response to my admin page for a plugin I am making at work. Just started in this position, and I am anxious through the roof over this basic Wordpress tuff that I can bot figure out.

This is my php index

```
<?php   
function php_design(){
?>
<div class="wrap">
            <h2>Priscalc Admin Panel</h2>
            <form 
                id="priscalc-form" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                class="priscalc-container" 
                method="post" 
                onsubmit="event.preventDefault();"
                action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>"
            >
                <?php
                    settings_fields( 'cg_settings' );
                    echo 
                    '
                    <div id="global-buttons">
                    <button class="button-secondary" id="ny-prisgruppe">Lag ny prisgruppe</button>
                    <button class="button-secondary slette" id="slett-ny-prisgruppe">Slett ny prisgruppe</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="prisgruppe-container">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:none;" id="add-remove">
                    <button class="button button-secondary" id="ny-prislinje">Ny prislinje</button>
                    <button style="display:none;" class="button button-secondary slette" id="fjern-prislinje">Fjern prislinje</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" "value="ny_prisgruppe"/>
                    ';
                    do_settings_sections( 'smashing_fields' );
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes" style="display: none;">'
                ?>
            </form>
<?php }
?>


<?php
/*function insert_prisgruppe(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $main_tb_name=$wpdb->prefix .'priscalc_tb_main';
        $content_tb_name=$wpdb->prefix .'priscalc_tb_content';
    
        $prisgruppe_navn = $_POST['prisgruppe_navn'];
        if(isset($_POST['emphasizedText-1']))$et1=$_POST['emphasizedText-1'];
        if(isset($_POST['followingText-1']))$ft1=$_POST['emphasizedText-1'];
        
        $wpdb->insert($content_tb_name,
            array(
                'id'=> $ft1,
                'prisgruppe_navn'=>$et1
            ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            )
        );

        die();
    }   
}*/

?>
```

This is my js

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        
        let contentConcat = "";
        let prisgruppeNavn = document.getElementById('prisgruppe-navn').value 
        for(let i = 1; i < prislinjer.childElementCount+1; i++){
            let following_text = document.getElementById('followingText-'+i).value;
            let emphasized_text = document.getElementById('emphasizedText-'+i).value;
            if(following_text.length<1 || emphasized_text.length<1 || prisgruppeNavn.length<1){
                alert("Du må fylle ut alle feltene.");
                return;
            }
            contentConcat+=emphasized_text+'_'+following_text+'@'
        }

        
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            action: 'insertData',
            dataType:"json",
            data: {"prisgruppe_navn": prisgruppeNavn,"prislinjer": contentConcat},
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my admin-ajax.php

```
function process_ny_prisgruppe(){
    return '[{"hei":"hei"}]';
}


add_action('wp_ajax_ny_prisgruppe','process_ny_prisgruppe');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ny_prisgruppe','process_ny_prisgruppe');
```

Comment: Your `action` parameter needs to be inside of `data`, see [AJAX in Plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#data).

Comment: Still no help looking like this.

$.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType:"json",
            data: {action: 'process_ny_prisgruppe',"prisgruppe_navn": prisgruppeNavn,"prislinjer": contentConcat},
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        });

Comment: I would simplify things for now. Skip AJAX and just get this working as a boring old HTML form. It is much easier to debug and the server doesn’t really care one or the other. Also make sure PHP, MySQL and WordPress error reporting are enabled.

Comment: Oh, also, your `action` parameter needs to match the name you're using with `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_`. According to your code `action` should be `ny_prisgruppe`, and you have `insertData`.

Comment: I now get a console log that says: {success: true, data: {…}}

Comment: Really wishing to return the parameters from the post request and print them in the console to assure it's all working like planned now

Comment: Well, since your original question has been answered and the AJAX call is no longer throwing a 400 error message you may want to open a new question to ask about handling the response object from the server (do try to research about it first, it seems you're not really familiar with AJAX yet).

Answer (score 0):

Your action parameter in your ajax call is not supposed to be a string but an object.
Change
`action: 'insertData',`

to
`action:{}`

The `{}` should have your data key and value pairs unless you are using same name for both key and value. Do this
`action:{name,age}`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer